# Django application database error: No module named

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I was trying to connect my database application to project in django.  Succeded on connecting psycopg and database. Then I started to build application for it by

```
python manage.py startapp books
```

and wrote some code in models.py.

But when I tried to put application in INSTALLED_APPS, it caused on error.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'tut1.books',
# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
 'django.contrib.admin',
# Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
# 'django.contrib.admindocs',
```

So, I'm in project's folder and type in Command Line:

```
%>python manage.py syncdb
ImportError: No module named 'tut1.books'
```

If I remove my app from INSTALLED_APPS, everything goes fine.
I suspect, there gotta be different syntax for linking application.

Tried to change 'tut1.books' to just 'books'. Causes another error.

```
%>python manage.py syncdb
AttributeError:'module' object has no attribute 'URLFIELD'
```

Files and folders in project /tut1/

```
   manage.py
   views.py
   /tut1/
   /templates/
   /books/
```

Files in /books/

```
   __init__.py
   modules.py
   views.py
   tests.py
```

Files in /tut1/tut1/

```
   __init__.py
   settings.py
   urls.py
   views.py
   wsgi.py
```

**init**.py is empty by default.

Checked PYTHONPATH for this project. Nothing odd...

```
>>> import sys
>>> for i in sys.path:
      print(i)


C:\study\django\tut1
C:\Python33\Lib\idlelib
C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools-1.1.6-py3.3.egg
C:\Python33\python33.zip
C:\Python33\DLLs
C:\Python33\lib
C:\Python33
C:\Python33\lib\site-packages
```

Comment: wild guess but does the folder tut1/books have an __init__.py ?

Comment: It all depends on how your `PYTHONPATH` is set up. Try adding just `'books'` instead of `'tut1.books'`.

Comment: so a python module will need a `__init__.py` file unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: There is no urls.py. That's why you had an 'AttributeError'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be a problem with models.py.
You seem to write code as follows.

```
foo = models.URLFIELD()
```

"models" module has no URLFIELD().

You should change it to URLField().

Comment: Yeah, cool. It had to be URLField(). I just typed it wrong. 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add an `__init__.py` file (it can be empty) to the folder tut1.books before python can import it. See this answer: [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Comment: It's there, empty by default.